# ServiceWorker with ES6 module imports (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker, es6-modules

Is it possible to use ES6 module imports in serviceworkers in latest Google Chrome?

I found this closed [thread](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/831) on w3c specs but it's not clear to me how to make it work on Google Chrome.

Tryied this but with no luck:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.mjs', {type:'module'})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this article "JS module support for shared workers and service workers is coming soon ..." https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules

Also, its tracked in this issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=680046

Comment: This issues is for dedicated workers. The issue specifically for service workers is: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=824647

Comment: Fixed on April 8th.